# How can I build a custom, dynamic ViewModel at runtime from data in existing data models?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3

So I am working on a web application and have encountered a new challenge that I have been stuck on for a few weeks.  I will provide background information regarding my application and my data models, as well as the desired end results.

Basic App Info & Context of the Problem:
My app is intended to serve as a tool which landscape contractors can use to help with managing their business operations.  My app will provide a place where they can create an account, then enter all of their customer information ("Client" data model), as well as the information about jobs they are doing for each of their clients ("Job" data model).  There is a one-to-many relationship between clients and jobs (one client can have many jobs, but only one client for any given job).

Background:
I have two simple data models, "Client" and "Job".  My app is being built in the ASP.net MVC3 framework.  Using the Entity Framework scaffolding mechanism, I have created the basic CRUD views for each of these data models (create, read, update, delete).  This is great for the most part (I can create new clients and jobs, and edit existing ones easy enough).

Business Problem:
I have the need to permit batch creating for new jobs in my application.  I want my users (landscape contractors) to be able to enter all the mowing jobs they completed for the day.  As such, I would like to have my view for this process populate a table with all active clients - each with a checkbox beside the row.  Then I would like the user to be able to check boxes for each client they did a new job for (mowed their lawn), and submit the form (enter jobs done), where the result would be new jobs created for each of these clients.

Technical Problem:
My best guess is that I need to create a custom ViewModel in the controller and send it to the view, where the ViewModel would be a list of new jobs created based on currently active clients.  Then in the view, the checkboxes could have the Client_ID (unique identifier for clients) as their value (this would be part of the ViewModel.  When the user submits the form, the view would pass the ViewModel back to the controller.  Then the controller could go through the list of ViewModel jobs and create a new job for each ViewModel job that has the checkbox checked.

So, my question is - how can I use the controller to do the following:
1.) Build a list of ViewModel jobs at runtime based on data from the Client list ("Client" data model)?
2.) How can I then pass that to the view?
3.) Once it comes back to the controller, how can I iterate through the list and modify my other data model accordingly (create new "Job" items)?

I created the custom ViewModel, which contains attributes from clients and jobs that I need to construct the new job entries (client name, client address, client id, job notes, crew, crew size, time on job, checkbox to indicate completion, etc.).  Let's say the user has 50 clients that he mows lawns for which are active clients.  I would want to construct a ViewModel with 50 rows (to represent each client that could possibly have their lawn mowed).  Then I want to send that to the view and display it with checkboxes, which indicate whether the lawn was cut or not.  When the model comes back to the view, the controller would then take the rows with checks in the checkboxes and create new "Job" rows in that table.

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide, I know this is probably an easy one for many of you.  I am new to C# and MVC3.

**UPDATE:**
Here is my code -

**Job Model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace LawnTracker.Models
{
    public class Job
    {
        [Key]
        public int Job_ID { get; set; }
        public int Client_ID { get; set; }
        public int Account_ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public string SvcRoute { get; set; }
        public string Service { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public double SvcPriceOverride { get; set; }
        public float SvcQty { get; set; }
        public string UofM { get; set; }
        public bool Invoiced { get; set; }
        public string Crew { get; set; }
        public int TechCount { get; set; }
        public string TimeStart { get; set; }
        public string TimeFinish { get; set; }
        public double TimeSpent { get; set; }
        public string Image1 { get; set; }
        public string Image2 { get; set; }
        public string Image3 { get; set; }
        public double MulchUsed { get; set; }
        public double FertUsed { get; set; }
        public double HerbUsed { get; set; }
        public string NextDue { get; set; }

    }


}
```

**My MowingJobViewModel model -**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace LawnTracker.Models
{
    public class MowingJobViewModel
    {
        public int Client_ID { get; set; }

        public bool Completed { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Street { get; set; }

        public string City { get; set; }

        public double SvcPriceOverride { get; set; }

        public string UofM { get; set; }

        public int SvcQty { get; set; }

        public string Notes { get; set; }

        public string Date { get; set; }

        public string Crew { get; set; }

        public int TechCount { get; set; }

        public string SvcRoute { get; set; }

        public string Schedule { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**And my JobController -**

```
 // GET: /Job/CreateMowing

        public ActionResult CreateMowing(string route = "", string sched = "")
        {
            List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
            listItems.Add(new SelectListItem()
            {
                Value = "Lump Sum",
                Text = "Lump Sum"
            });
            listItems.Add(new SelectListItem()
            {
                Value = "Hours",
                Text = "Hours"
            });


            ViewBag.Units = new SelectList(listItems, "Value", "Text");
            ViewBag.Routes = db.Clients.Select(r => r.SvcRoute).Distinct();
            ViewBag.Sched = db.Clients.Select(r => r.MowSched).Distinct();

            var model = from r in db.Clients
                        orderby r.SvcRoute
                        where (r.Mowing == true) &&
                        (r.Status == "Active") &&
                        (r.SvcRoute == route || (route == "")) &&
                        (r.MowSched == sched || (sched == "")) 
                        select r;
            if (model.Count() > 0)
            {
                ViewBag.total = model.Select(r => r.MowPrice).Sum();
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.total = 0.00;
            }

           /* Build a list of MowingJobViewModel objects based on the above defined list of clients
            * who are subscribed to mowing and active. This will enable batch entry for new jobs done.
            * This list of MowingJobViewModel objects will be sent to the client after a HTTP GET
            * request for the CreateMowing view.  The user will be able to check boxes associated
            * with each client in the client list.  When the form is submitted, the controller
            * receives the model back with the updated information (completed, notes, etc.) about
            * each job.  Then the controller must update the jobs table, adding the new jobs based on 
            * the view model returned from the view / client.
            * 
            */

            //Create a new list of MowingJobViewModel objects
             IEnumerable<MowingJobViewModel> mjList = new List<MowingJobViewModel>();

            //iterate through the list of clients built from earlier (in model)...
             foreach (var item in model)
             {  
             //create new MowingJobViewModel object MJ and add it to the list
             mjList.Add(new MowingJobViewModel()
             {
               Client_ID = item.Client_ID,
               Completed = false,
               Name = (item.FirstName + " " + item.LastName),
               Street = item.Address1,
               City = item.City,
               SvcPriceOverride = item.MowPrice,
               UofM = "Lump Sum",
               SvcQty = 1,
               Notes = "",
               Date = "",
               Crew = "",
               TechCount = 2,
               SvcRoute = item.SvcRoute,
               Schedule = item.MowSched,
              });

             }

             return View(mjList);

             }

**I don't have my view ("CreateMowing.cshtml") worked out correctly, but here is what I have-**

@model IEnumerable<LawnTracker.Models.MowingJobViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Enter Mowing Jobs";
}

<h2>Enter Mowing Jobs</h2>

<div style="float: left; clear:both; width: 100%;">
    <b>Total Jobs: @Html.Encode(Model.Count())</b><br />
    <b>Total Revenue: $@Html.Encode(ViewBag.total)</b><br /><br />
</div>
<p></p>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div style="float: right; clear:both; width: 100%;">
     @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateMowing", "Job", FormMethod.Get)) 
    {
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>

        <th>
            Route
        </th>

        <th>Schedule</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Show:
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DropDownList("route", new SelectList(ViewBag.Routes), "--ALL--")            
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DropDownList("sched", new SelectList(ViewBag.Sched), "--ALL--")
        </td>
        <td>            
            <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table><br /><br />

    }
</div>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Completed
        </th>
        <th>
            First Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Last Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Street
        </th>

        <th>
            City
        </th>

        <th>
            Service Route
        </th>
        <th>
            Price
        </th>

        <th>
            Units
        </th>

        <th>
            Qty
        </th>
        <th>
            Notes
        </th>

        <th>
            Schedule
        </th>

    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="invoiced" value="@item.Client_ID" >
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address1)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SvcRoute)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MowPrice)
        </td>

        <td>

        </td>

        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MowSched)
        </td>

     </tr>
}

</table>


<div>
    <br />
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've created a view-model that contains the display attributes / data entry fields for a particular client when creating a job.  Since you didn't give it a name, I'll call it `NewJobEntry`.  As you guessed, you now need a view-model that has a property of type `List<NewJobEntry>` to represent a variable number of new jobs that can be created at once.

Your controller will populate the list, adding a `NewJobEntry` instance for each client.

Your view, when provided the model containing the list, can enumerate the list and generate a row for each `NewJobEntry`.

Once the data is posted back to your controller, the default ASP.NET MVC binder can handle lists but there are some quirks.  The default binder will automatically hydrate objects in a list so long as the field names have sequential indices.  To ensure these indices are correctly generated, you will want to bind using lambda expressions in your view that have a sequential index:

`Html.CheckboxFor(model => model.JobList[i].IsSelected)`

You might consider using a `for` loop instead of a `foreach` loop when enumerating your list.

You also have to be careful with checkboxes, because an unchecked checkbox does not actually appear in the post data sent to the controller.  This will break binding, because the indices sent in the post data may no longer be sequential (there will be gaps wherever there are unchecked checkboxes).  Therefore, I would recommend you include a hidden field for the client Id.  This way, the post data will always contain at least one field with the appropriate sequential index for each list entry.

`Html.HiddenFor(model => model.JobList[i].ClientId)`

Now your post data will be something along the lines of:

```
JobList_0_IsSelected=true
JobList_0_ClientId=12345
JobList_1_ClientId=12346
JobList_2_IsSelected=true
JobList_2_ClientId=12347
```

The default binder will handle this and rebuild your list.  Note that without the hidden field for client Id, index `1` would be missing, and the default binder would not correctly rebuild the list.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I will post my code here tomorrow, along with some more questions.  Thanks so much!